# How to route AWS Application Load Balancer to appropriate webservers hosted on the same EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

1. I have one Amazon EC2 Instance (lets refer to as EC2)
2. I have two webservers running on EC2
3. First webserver A running on port 80 (docker container)
4. Second webserver B running on port 50 (docker container)
5. I two target groups, TGA and TGB
6. TGA --> port 80, http, with EC2 (I can access using the EC2 IPV4)
7. TGB --> port 50, http, with EC2 (I can access using the EC2 IPV4:50)
8. I have a application load balancer with 2 rules
9. If path is "/", then forward to TGA
10. If path is "/docs", then forward to TGB

When I access the load balancer, step 9 is working
When I tried to access the load balancer, with the path "/docs", I was expecting to get to TGB:50/docs, but it is not working

I think I have a misunderstanding somewhere in the port translation or how it is supposed to work. Can any please help me clarify where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the /docs rule is defined in the top so it will have the priority to be matched against,

and the / rule should be down so it will be the default to be applied

Comment: it is... "/docs" is the first rule and "/" is second one..

Comment: it should work then, please send a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the procedure that I described above is working.

I have no explanation why it was not working earlier, only explanation being that most probably all the changes that I kept on making takes some time to go deep and take root.